# I unpublish my chrome extension by mistake, how could I republish it in the same location?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

The extension used to reside here:   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beanote-note-taking-on-pa/nikccehomlnjkmgmhnieecolhgdafajb

[image]

There is no republish button....

I really appreciate if someone help me with it... ><

Thanks

Comment: you'll have to wait until the "pending review" disappears.  It may take a few days, then you should be able to republish and it will keep the same extension id.

Comment: You can find more information about "pending review" on https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-08

Comment: Wait for one day and then I am able to republish!  Thanks a lot!!